# Stop and Resume SVG animation that is imported in an img tag

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I have an animated SVG that imported in the img tag

```
<img src="animated-logo.svg"/>
```

I would like to include an stop and resume function for the animation.**For example**:if the user hovers the mouse pointer on the image the animation stops and resumes if the pointer is out of the image

Is there any way to do this by just using the img tag alone (i.e., without making changes to original svg file)?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I think your best bet would be to use a static image and then animate it with css

Comment: @akashabi This is not possible, images are not interactive.

Comment: @RobertLongson I just don't want to make changes to original SVG file.That's the only requirement I have.The import method can be changed,if needed.

Comment: you could use an <iframe> or <object> tag instead.